# How to simplify this complex expression into this other one?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to simplify this :
$$
\dfrac{-\sqrt{x}+\dfrac{\left( \sqrt{x}+1\right) ^{2}}{2\sqrt{x}}-1}{( \sqrt{x} + 1)^4}
$$

to this :

$$
\dfrac{1-\sqrt{x}}{2\left( \sqrt{x}+1\right)^{3}\sqrt{x}}
$$

I don't even know where to start. It would be nice if someone could show me each of the step required to arrive to the above expression while mentioning what rules are being used.

Comment: Start by factoring by $\sqrt x +1$ in the numerator.

Comment: Start by multiplying numerator and denominator by$2\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 1):

The numerator can easily be rewritten as follows: $\ - \sqrt{x} + \frac{(\sqrt{x} +1)^{2}}{2 \sqrt{x}} - 1 = - (\sqrt{x} + 1) + \frac{(\sqrt{x} +1)^{2}}{2 \sqrt{x}} = (\sqrt{x}+1)(-1 + \frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{2\sqrt{x}})$.

Now you can divide both numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{x} + 1$. If you then multiply numerator and denominator by $2 \sqrt{x}$, you will get the desired result.